# How to detect printer connected in same wifi network in android

Tags: android, printing, wifi

My android application need to print over wifi printer.Here wifi printer will be connected on same network. How to detect that printer from android ?

Can any give hint for same ?

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use the [Google Cloud](http://code.google.com/apis/cloudprint/docs/overview.html) Printing [API](http://code.google.com/apis/cloudprint/docs/devguide.html) . It works well with Android.

Comment: I am also using "Google Cloud" .But that is different way.I want to print file using wifi local printer also.Can you give me any hint ?